# Java creating multiple objects

Tags: java, loops, object, vector, while-loop

I have created a class to define objects called `Data` which store Line Number, Variable Value, and Variable Name in strings.
I want to populate the data objects with information taken in from a txt file and stored in the string variable `line`, and I am using the below while loop to populate my data objects:

```
while(line !=null){
            input.setLN(line);
            line = inputBuffer.readLine();
            input.setVN(line);
            line = inputBuffer.readLine();
            input.setVV(line);
            line = inputBuffer.readLine();
            counter ++;
```

However, I would then like to add each individual `Data` object to a `Vector` (it must be done using a `Vector`) so I can store each LN,VN,VV and be able to output them from the Vector.

I have declared the Vector of `Data` objects using the following code:

```
Vector<Data> myVector=new Vector<Data>();
```

However, every iteration of the while loop overwrites the previous values assigned to the data object, so only one `Data` object is stored in the vector when I use the following code at the bottom of my while loop:

```
myVector.add(input);
```

I am aware that I need to create a copy of `input` after each iteration of the loop, and store that copy into the `Vector` before taking new values into `input`, however I am unsure of how to best do this.

Any advice appreciated

Comment: The variable scope matters here. If you declared "input" before your "while" loop, only one instance will be created, so every change you make to it will be reflected in the vector's content. Eran's answer is good because the "Data" object in created inside the loop, so each iteration will create a new instance.

Comment: How/Where would I then add these Data objects to my Vector?

Comment: Any place between "Data input = new Data();" and the end of your loop will be fine

Answer (score 2):

> I am aware I need to create a copy of input after each iteration of the loop and store that copy into the Vector before taking new values into input however I am unsure of how to best do this.

How about :

```
while(line !=null) {
    Data input = new Data();
    input.setLN(line);
    line = inputBuffer.readLine();
    input.setVN(line);
    line = inputBuffer.readLine();
    input.setVV(line);
    line = inputBuffer.readLine();
    counter ++;
    ...
    myVector.add(input);
}
```

Comment: How/Where would I then add these Data objects to my Vector?

Comment: @AndiStevenson You would add them at the end of each iteration of the loop. See edit